# Windows IoT core watcher empty

Tags: windows-iot

My Windows IoT Core Watcher is empty, even though I am able to locate my Raspberry Pi using the router's list of connected devices and I am not able to deploy an app from visual studio 2015, showing error Device cannot be found.  Any ideas why is the Watcher empty and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you running Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to "have" that tool. It just tell you what the IP address of the Pi is. It is possible that your firewall is blocking it or there is a known problem with Windows 10 compatibility.

If you know the IP address, you can just put that into to Visual Studio and everything will work as normal.